# sra toolkit fastq-dump comand not terminating

Tags: sratoolkit

I ran the following command trying to download a fasta file from NIH but the command doesn't seem to terminate and I get no output file in my repository:

```
fastq-dump SRR10134980
```

I have installed SRA Toolkit following the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/02.-Installing-SRA-Toolkit).

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you use [fasterq-dump](https://github.com/ncbi/sra-tools/wiki/HowTo:-fasterq-dump)? Note that `fasterq-dump` is the successor to the older `fastq-dump` tool.

Answer (score 1):

That's an 11GB file and fastq-dump is not a speedster. Without more info the likely answer is that it keeps downloading which might take several hours on  poor connection. You can get fastq download links from sra-explorer.info -- That is more stable than this tool.